# Prove an inequality for an exponential function.

Tags: calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion

I need to prove the following inequality:

$\displaystyle e^x > \frac{x^n}{n!}$, for any $x\geqslant0$

I understand I need to use taylor's expansion somehow but not sure how.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the taylor expansion of $e^x$ ?

Comment: $\sum\frac{x^k}{k!}$, but what do I have to say to prove what I want?

Answer (score 2):

$$e^x=\sum \frac{x^k}{k!}>\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Is it that short? I mean.. no any explanation needed?

Comment: $x \geq 0$ matters a lot here. Can you see why?

Comment: @joshRqe You have to justify why the inequality in my answer holds as suggested by krirkrirk. This is not a homework-solving site. I gave you enough hint to finish the question on your own after adding minor details.

Comment: Short is good, and Sahiba's answer is all that is needed

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor expansion for $e^{x}$ is 
$$e^{x} = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{k}}{k!} + \cdots.$$
For any power of $x$ chosen there are other terms in the expansion as seen by
$$e^{x} - \frac{x^{n}}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{k}}{k!} + \cdots.$$
From this it is fairly evident that
$$e^{x} > \frac{x^{n}}{n!}.$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to write $$\begin{align} e^x & = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac {x^n}{n!} + \cdots\cdots \\ & > \frac{x^n}{n!} \text{ ?} \end{align} $$

Comment: BTW your first-degree terms appears twice.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, it would have been easer as you have mentioned, but here it was intended to demonstrate that any power, say $0 \leq n \leq k$, could be subtracted from both sides and still have that many minus one terms remaining.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this also by induction, using integrals.

Let's prove it for $n=1$. The function $f_1(x)=e^x-x$ has derivative $f_1'(x)=e^x-1$ which is positive for $x>0$. Therefore $f$ is increasing over $[0,\infty)$ and, since $f_1(0)=1>0$, we are done.

Let's assume now that $f_n(x)=e^x-x^n/n!$ is positive for $x\ge0$. Then, for $x\ge0$,
$$
f_{n+1}(x)-1=\int_0^{x}f_n(t)\,dt\ge0
$$
so $f_{n+1}(x)\ge1$, for every $x\ge0$.

Actually, we have proved that $f_n(x)\ge1$, for every $x\ge0$.